# Computing symmetric Kullback-Leibler divergence between two documents

Tags: python, nlp, similarity, information-retrieval

I have followed the paper [here](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/facilities/public/AD/Text%20Categorization/Using%20Kullback-Leibler%20Distance%20for%20Text%20Categorization.pdf) and the code [here](https://gist.github.com/mrorii/961963) (it is implemented using the symmetric kld and a back-off model proposed in the paper in the 1st link) for computing KLD between two text data sets. I have changed the for-loop in the end to return the probability distribution of two data sets to test if both sum to 1:

```
import re, math, collections

def tokenize(_str):
    stopwords = ['and', 'for', 'if', 'the', 'then', 'be', 'is', \
                 'are', 'will', 'in', 'it', 'to', 'that']
    tokens = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0.)
    for m in re.finditer(r"(\w+)", _str, re.UNICODE):
        m = m.group(1).lower()
        if len(m) < 2: continue
        if m in stopwords: continue
        tokens[m] += 1

    return tokens
#end of tokenize

def kldiv(_s, _t):
    if (len(_s) == 0):
        return 1e33

    if (len(_t) == 0):
        return 1e33

    ssum = 0. + sum(_s.values())
    slen = len(_s)

    tsum = 0. + sum(_t.values())
    tlen = len(_t)

    vocabdiff = set(_s.keys()).difference(set(_t.keys()))
    lenvocabdiff = len(vocabdiff)

    """ epsilon """
    epsilon = min(min(_s.values())/ssum, min(_t.values())/tsum) * 0.001

    """ gamma """
    gamma = 1 - lenvocabdiff * epsilon

    """ Check if distribution probabilities sum to 1"""
    sc = sum([v/ssum for v in _s.itervalues()])
    st = sum([v/tsum for v in _t.itervalues()])

    ps=[] 
    pt = [] 
    for t, v in _s.iteritems(): 
        pts = v / ssum 
        ptt = epsilon 
        if t in _t: 
            ptt = gamma * (_t[t] / tsum) 
        ps.append(pts) 
        pt.append(ptt)
    return ps, pt
```

I have tested with

`d1 = """Many research publications want you to use BibTeX, which better
organizes the whole process. Suppose for concreteness your source
file is x.tex. Basically, you create a file x.bib containing the
bibliography, and run bibtex on that file."""
d2 = """In this case you must supply both a \left and a \right because the
delimiter height are made to match whatever is contained between the
two commands. But, the \left doesn't have to be an actual 'left
delimiter', that is you can use '\left)' if there were some reason
to do it."""`

`sum(ps)` = 1  but `sum(pt)` is way smaller than 1 when:

[image: This should be the case.]

Is there something that is not correct in the code or else? Thanks!

**Update:**

In order to make both pt and ps sum to 1, I had to change the code to:

```
    vocab = Counter(_s)+Counter(_t)
    ps=[] 
    pt = [] 
    for t, v in vocab.iteritems(): 
        if t in _s:
            pts = gamma * (_s[t] / ssum) 
        else: 
            pts = epsilon

        if t in _t: 
            ptt = gamma * (_t[t] / tsum) 
        else:
            ptt = epsilon

        ps.append(pts) 
        pt.append(ptt)

    return ps, pt
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, in your test strings (d1 and d2), you should use two consecutive backslashes. The backslash character is used for escaping in python.  Example: `x="\\left"` instead of `x="\left"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sum(ps) and sum(pt) are the total probability mass of _s and _t **over the support of s** (by "support of s" I mean all words that appear in _s, regardless of the words that appear in _t).
This means that

1. sum(ps)==1, since the for-loop sums over all words in _s.
2. sum(pt) <= 1, where equality will hold if the support of t is a subset of the support of s (that is, if all words in _t appear in _s). Also, sum(pt) might be close to 0 if the overlap between words in _s and _t is small. Specifically, if the intersection of _s and _t is the empty set, then sum(pt) == epsilon*len(_s).

So, I don't think there's a problem with the code.

Also, contrary to the title of the question, kldiv() does not compute the symmetric KL-divergence, but the KL-divergence between _s and a smoothed version of _t.

Comment: Thanks Tomer! "They are probabilities over the support of s" makes sense now. Though in the paper it did state this is symmetric KLD, do you think is the implementation here that is a bit off?

Comment: Hi Tomer, I have made some small changes from the [original code](https://gist.github.com/mrorii/961963), and it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bluemonk482/f3e2fd35a774a61dbedd). The modified code computes ps and pt based on their vocab union, rather than relying on the support of s. Do you think this is a better version of kld than the original implementation, to measure the distance between two text corpus? Thanks so much!

Comment: The original function computes KL( _s || smoothed(_t) ). Note that the smoothing is there to handle an edge case where _t's support is in mismatch with _s (consider w in _s that does not appear in _t, in which case log(t(w)) = log(0) = -inf, which would make KL = inf). To compute the symmetric KL, simply compute (kldiv(_s, _t) + kldiv(_t, _s)) / 2.

Comment: Thanks. I think they are both effective ways to compute KL distance.

Comment: What exactly is Epsilon and Gamma in the program?

Answer (score 0):

The sum of your probability distributions for each document are stored in the variables `sc` and `st`, those are close to 1.